# Open Source Data Mining Software

Tags: open-source, associations, data-mining

I was wondering; what is the best open source software that I can use for non-binary association rule generations. I need a non-binary implementation because converting my currently non-binary data to binary data would not give the desired results.

Thanks and can't wait to here your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Orange data mining toolkit.

http://www.ailab.si/orange/

Comment: Actually, these days I like knime: http://knime.org

Answer (score 4):

Also take a look at [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/)

Comment: Thanks! After posting this question, that was the first one that I ran across. We actually ended up using Weka to run analysis on some data sets we had collected.

Answer (score 3):

Check out:

RapidMiner

and

R with Rattle

Answer (score 1):

Try [Data Mining SDK](http://datamining.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Used it for one of my projects... pretty good

Answer (score 0):

These days I like Knime. See http://knime.org.

Answer (score 0):

I have an open-source software named SPMF with more than **130 algorithms** related to association rules mining, frequent itemset mining, sequential rule mining and sequential pattern mining.  You can check my [webpage](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) for more details and to download it:

It is Java source code. It has a simple graphical user interface. It also has many specialized algorithms that you will not find in other data mining software.

Answer (score 0):

you could even try another one called Tanagra http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/en/tanagra.html

Its mainly for research purpose but works well and has good tutorials here 
http://data-mining-tutorials.blogspot.com